# Organisations like AI and HRW but more anti-anti-semitic

Tags: human-rights, ngos

As of 11 January, there's no hits on [AI](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=hypercacher%20site:amnesty.org) or [HRW](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=hypercacher%20site:hrw.org) about the deadly attack on the French Jewish supermarket HyperCacher, while by contrast HRW has [condemned](http://www.hrw.org/news/2015/01/08/france-attack-free-expression) the attack on Charlie Hebdo and attacks against Muslim places of worship.

Are there any general-purpose human rights organisations like Amnesty International or Human Rights Watch, but are more actively opposed to anti-semitism? (By general purpose, I mean organisations that try to oppose a wide range of human rights abuses, rather than focusing on a single specific issue or hatred against a specific race or religion)

Comment: So far, the hostage taking in the kasher supermarket has not been claimed as an antisemitic act.

Comment: This is kind of an open-ended opinion based question. I'm not sure it's a good one for SE. There's no one right answer and which answer people prefer is really a matter of opinion.